# Unity Canvas Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, canvas

Knows how to operate animations linked to characters when conditions are met.

I am using a first person camera.

If the conditions are met, the character needs to animate the mouth hide, but since it's from the first person camera
Depending on the camera's point of view, the animation to cover the mouth may not be visible or the hand position may rise as much as the eyes height.

So, is there a way to animate the character's hand at a fixed position on the camera, regardless of the camera's viewpoint and field of view, like the text on the canvas (subtitle)?

Use a translator
Sorry that the question is not smooth.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXBPE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVE36.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, with the `animator`, you can create some interesting things like what you were asking for. If you are trying to have an animation always with the same position related to an object you can do this:

In the Animation window, with the `Player` (state) selected, or anything else, click the Add Property button. Do not select the root Transform object but instead select a second game object(your main camera) and choose camera> Transform > Position. You can also use other properties, but it depends on your use.

At this point, you will see the Position property of the object in the Animation window with two keyframes added to the timeline, one at 0:00 and one at 1:00.

Now you can simply use the `Record` button and change the position relative to the object while you are also animating your player like the guy in GTA who goes on a car or pressing a button.

Comment: Thank you.
I haven't confirmed it yet, but seeing the use of the camera's position seems to be the answer I want.